# Determine $P(X + 2Y \leq 3)$ from $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = ke^{-\lambda x}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Question**

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with joint density

\begin{align}
f_{X, Y}(x, y) &=
\begin{cases}
ke^{-\lambda x} \text{ for } 0 < y < x < \infty\\
0 \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

**(a)** Find $k$.

**(b)** Derive the marginal density for $Y$ and hence evaluate $\text{E}(Y), \text{E}(Y^2)$ and $\text{Var}(Y)$.

**(c)** Find $P(X + 2Y \leq 3)$.

**Attempt**

I found parts (a) and (b) relatively simple, but I can't figure out how to solve (c). I will quickly go over parts (a) and (b) before I get to (c).

**(a)** To determine $k$ involves solving the equation below for $k$:

\begin{align}
1 &= \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^xke^{-\lambda x} dy dx.
\end{align}

I found the answer to be $k = \lambda^2$.

**(b)** To find $f_Y(y)$ I compute the integral

\begin{align}
\int_y^{\infty} \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda x} dx &= \lambda e^{-\lambda y}
\end{align}

and I conclude that $Y \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ and therefore the first and second moments and the variance can be quickly calculated or looked up.

**(c)** I had a couple ideas for how to approach this problem. One idea was to try the change of variables formula with $U = X + 2Y$ and $V = Y$ in order to determine $f_{U, V}(u, v)$ and then integrate out $V$. I must have made one or more errors when I did this because my answer was $f_U(u) = \frac{1}{2}\lambda(1 - e^{-\frac{1}{3}\lambda u})$, which is definitely not a valid density.

The second idea I had was to determine $f_X(x)$ and see if I might get lucky and determine that $X + 2Y$ has a form that I'd recognize. However, the answer I got was $f_X(x) = \lambda^2 xe^{-\lambda x}$ and this doesn't look like any kind of density I know, so this approach didn't work for me either.

Does anyone know what the proper approach is for part (c) of this question? Thank you.

Comment: you found $f_y$, do some algebra in $P(X+2Y\leq 3)$ and the use $f_y$

Comment: So if $F_Y(y)$ is the cdf of $Y$, then it's simply $F_Y(\frac{3-X}{2})$?

Comment: @Novice, no; not quite that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Yes.

(b) Yes.

(c) $\mathsf P(X+2Y<3) ~{=~ \iint_{0<y<\min\{x, (3-x)/2\}} \lambda^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}~\mathrm d (y,x)\\=\int_0^3 F_Y(\min\{x,(3-x)/2\})~\mathrm d x\\=\int_0^1 F_Y(x)~\mathrm d x+\int_1^3 F_Y((3-x)/2)~\mathrm d x}$

Where $F_Y(y)= (1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda y})\mathbf 1_{0<y}$